# Five sums are negative and five sums are positive. How many products are positive?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**This is a problem from Tournament of Town competition taking place today. Please don't amswer.**

There are 5 non-zero numbers. One has calculated the sum of each two numbers. Among the sums five are negative and five are positive. How many products are positive?

Comment: Is it possible that all five numbers are of the same sign?

Comment: It is impossible that they have the same sign. We won't get a positive/negative sum in that case.

Comment: Again, it is impossible because we won't get five negative products.

Answer (score 1):

We must have $2$ numbers of one sign and $3$ of the other, since otherwise there would be at least ${4\choose2}=6$ pairwise sums of the same sign. The number of negative pairwise products is therefore ${2\choose1}{3\choose1}=6$, which leaves $4$ positive pairwise products.